# Change button border and disabled appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have 2 Buttons in my form. Both have background image and Flat style is "Flat".

1. On clicking <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, when the focus is on button, I see solid color rectangle inner, instead of solid border I want to have dotted border in the button.
2. When the button is clicked, some activity is going on and the button is disabled. While disabled, the button text color changes to grey. I don't want it to change the text color. I believe this is windows standard behavior, but how do I not change the text color when the button is selected?

I can't find any properties to set these points. What should I do to achieve the goal. Any help is highly appreciated.

I also created a custom button, but can't get rid of the above issues.

My custom button's paint method :

```
   public partial class MyButton : Button  {

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        // Set custom fore color    
        base.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 254, 255);    

        // set the same forecolor even if the button is disabled  
        if (base.Enabled == false)
        {
            base.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 254, 255);
        }

    }  //OnPaint method ends
  }  // class ends
```

**UPDATED Soluiton for (1) & (2)**
ADDED the following in onpaint() :

```
    private void init()
    {
        base.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 254, 255);
        base.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 254);   // Transparent border
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);

        if (base.ContainsFocus)
        {
            // Draw inner dotted rectangle when button is on focus
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 3);
            Point p = base.Location;
            pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(4, 4, Size.Width - 8, Size.Height - 8);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pevent.Graphics, rectangle);
        }

        // Draw the string to screen
        SizeF sf = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString(displayText, this.Font, this.Width);
        Point ThePoint = new Point();
        ThePoint.X = (int)((this.Width / 2) - (sf.Width / 2));
        ThePoint.Y = (int)((this.Height / 2) - (sf.Height / 2));
        //pevent.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), ThePoint);
        //pevent.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 254, 255)), ThePoint);
        pevent.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), ThePoint);
        //this.Text = "";
     }//OnPaint ends

    // Avoids the inner solid rectangle shown on focus
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This successfully draws a dotted line in my button indicating for focus. To get rid of the default solid line I overridded ShowFocusCues().

This has helped me solve 1 completely. But with point 2, not getting 100% results. I created a property "displayText" in my MyButton class. In OnPaint(), if I give ForeColor, Color.FromARGB to SolidBrush, it doesn't show up any text. But if I pass Color.Black, then it accepts it and shows the text in Black color. Why is it not accepting the ForeColor, or custom color and only accepting default Colors'? Where am I still going wrong for this simple task. I tried the same by implementing button_paint in the form, but I see same results.

Any idea where am I still going wrong ???

Comment: `Focus` is the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: Change Button Text and Border line style and colors in "button3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)"

Comment: @husnain, added paint event for my custom button. For (2) when btn is clicked and activity is going on its Enabled is set to false. But even after the code added, the text color is of gray color only after clicked. REG border line style, I am not aware of how do I change and set it, can you show a snaippet or methods to use.  -Thanks

Comment: Both of these are part of the standard Button class, as far as I know you can't override this behavior. You will have to create custom button from scratch (inherit from Control rather than Button) and handle everything yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, if I inherit from Control, what more do I need to handle ?

Comment: @Tvd everything: you will need to draw the text and handle all events.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, find the solution in my question. I has solved all that I was looking for. Good Luck......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     private void button3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {

                SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                Pen pen = new Pen(br);
                pen.Width = 3;
                pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
                  // to draw left border
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, this.button3.Width));
                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor); //Use the ForeColor property
                // Draw string to screen.
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Sample", Font, drawBrush, 5f, 3f);
                this.button3.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks husnain. I added the code that I have used for point 1. And now I can get the dotted line inner button on focus and it goes away when off focus. But I still get the default solid line. How do I get rid of that default solid line ?

Comment: I got rid of that solid rect also. Now just point (3) is not yet solved. Why so ???

Comment: Oh sorry, its (2) When the button is clicked, some activity is going on and the button is disabled. While disabled, the button text color changes to grey. I don't want it to change the text color. --- I added if(base.Enabled == false), but that also doesn't seem to have any impact. Where am I going wrong. Have updated oppaint()

Comment: @husian, Please check the above code of OnPaint(). I am not able to set custom color to dispaly the text. Rest all is working just stuck up with custom color. Kindly help me out with that at the earliest. Please.

Comment: hohhh, did it. I create SolidBrush as new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 254, 255))  & it did the work.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @husian, kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427069/c-sharp-painting-text-on-button-difference-in-look   If u can help me with this also.