# Painting text on Button - Difference in look

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, paint

I have my custom button where I have overridden the OnPaint() and draw the text in it only. On runtime the text looks differently - spacing between chars is lacking. Here is the image of design & runtime of the button :
[image]

The paint methods is as:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    base.OnPaint(pevent);

    if (base.ContainsFocus)
    {
        // Draw inner dotted rectangle when button is on focus
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 3);
        Point p = base.Location;
        pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(4, 4, Size.Width - 8, 
                                            Size.Height - 8);
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pevent.Graphics, rectangle);
    }

    // Draw the string to screen
    SizeF sf = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString(displayText, this.Font, 
                                             this.Width);
    Point ThePoint = new Point();
    ThePoint.X = (int)((this.Width / 2) - (sf.Width / 2));
    ThePoint.Y = (int)((this.Height / 2) - (sf.Height / 2));
    pevent.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, Font, 
              new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 254, 255)), ThePoint);
    this.Text = "";
}
```

Any idea where am I going wrong and how to take care of the same?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: @Falle1234, Font - Arial Rounded MT Bold, 9pt

Comment: Consider using the [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext.aspx) method, instead.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem but couldn't. This suggests to me that it isn't a problem with your onPaint method. Maybe some other setting in your custom button control is messing it up somehow.

Comment: I have never tried any of this but by default some code is being added to the `Program` class: `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` and `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` - could these have anything to do with the issue? Those might not be set while designing.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Really which font do you use? Font - Arial Rounded MT Bold, 9p no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct smoothing mode like this:

```
Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
```

Then, the result should look OK.

Answer (score 0):

[Devils Child's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10511103/366904) will affect the quality of lines and circles, etc.

But for text rendering, you can use:

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
```