# Coloured alphabet in button text of windows forms button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am working on a project where I have assigned assigned shortcut keys to button . My requirement is to highlight only that alphabet of text written on button control so that the user knows that by pressing that letter key on keyboard , the shortcut key for that button can be triggered . I have search the whole internet but don't find any ideas.

Comment: Is this a regular winforms button control? Because I don't think you can style the text on those.

Comment: Yes , it is a regular winforms button control

Comment: You can prepend the shortcut letter with a "&" in the button text and it will automatically be recognized as shortcut key and will be displayed as underlined. See: [Add an access key shortcut to a control (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-access-keys?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Comment: See also: [Developing Custom Windows Forms Controls with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: If you are referring to shortcuts in the format of: `Action (ALT + T)` where inside of the `( )` is the keyboard shortcut. You could possibly use a control such as: Telerik WinForms as seen below: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/buttons/button/customizing-appearance/html-like-text-formatting which will allow you to use HTML formatting for the text inside of the button so you could do something like: `<color=Black>Action <color=Red>(ALT + T)` which would highlight the `(ALT + T)` in Red next to the black `Action`

Comment: DRAW the text (with your specific coloring) into a Bitmap and then display that in the Button instead of normal text.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use paid controls (Telerik, Infragistics) then you would need to create your own control and code the drawing yourself.

If you create a custom control that derives from the `Button` class, the simplest way to go is to override the `OnPaint` method.

You might want to see example like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427069/painting-text-on-button-difference-in-look), the [other one](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/770872/how-to-use-two-colors-in-label-for-text-in-csharp#answer4), or [the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244392/how-to-correctly-get-a-winforms-button-control-to-draw-custom-text).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '&' for "highlighting" a letter on a Button.

Example:

```
button1.Text = "&Button1";
button2.Text = "Butt&on2";
button3.Text = "Button&3";
```

This is the Result:

[image]